# Sorting string in Access DB

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a DB with field Version. There might be many records with the same version string, so to pull out versions I have, I do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblSample.Version
FROM tblSample
ORDER BY tblSample.Version DESC;
```

Here is sample data:

```
tblSample.Version
1.1.1000
1.2.1654
1.15.1223
1.2.1654
1.1.1000
```

What I get after executing query:

```
1.2.1654
1.15.1223
1.1.1000
```

What I want to get is(because 15 is obviously > 2 and 1):

```
1.15.1223
1.2.1654
1.1.1000
```

Respectively other octets should be considered as well.

Comment: Your data is improperly structured if you need to sort by sub-strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you want to `sort` on x and do a `distinct` on y you need to do the distinct first (hence the subquery)

Using the following function (modified from [fredg's answer in this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/498406-vba-function-within-access-query))
Note: the function uses the [split](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx) function which I think is appropriate here.

```
Public Function ParseText(TextIn As String, X) As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim var As Variant

    var = Split(TextIn, ".", -1)
    ParseText = var(X)

End Function
```

You can write this SQL Statement

```
SELECT  t.Version
FROM 
    ( SELECT Distinct tblSample.Version
      FROM tblSample.Version) t
ORDER BY 
    Cint(ParseText([t.Version],0)) DESC , 
    Cint(ParseText([t.Version],1)) DESC , 
    Cint(ParseText([t.Version],2)) DESC;
```

**Upate**
As HansUp noted. You also need to cast to an int to get the sorting correctly. You can either do this in the SQL (as my updated answer has) or you can do this in ParseText and return an int

Comment: Unless I missed something, this answer will still not sort 1.15.1223 before 1.2.1654 in DESC order.

Comment: +1 But would you actually use this approach, CF?  Seems to me the 3 components of Version rightfully belong in separate numeric fields.  This Version attribute smells like one of those identifiers folks create by concatenating year, Project_ID, and so forth.  If you want that, don't store it; store the sub-elements, and do the concatenation on demand as needed.

Comment: @HansUp. I agree that the probably should be three separate fields, but regrettably the cost of doing so may not justify the value of that change.

Comment: As long as the data is not properly stored, you're going to risk performance problems, since the ORDER BY clause above is not sargable.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is analogous to [sorting IP addresses](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sort-ip-addresses-in-an-access-database-HP001164613.aspx).  You can follow the exact same techniques outlined in that article to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: They are not querying distinct values... I guess this is the key point.

Comment: Then you should be able to integrate Conrad Frix's suggestion to put the Distinct in a subquery.  To make it easier to work with you could save that subquery as a standalone query.  Treat the saved query as your base table and everything in the link I provided should work from there.

Answer (score 2):

Store Version as 3 numeric fields.

```
major minor release
    1     1    1000
    1     2    1654
    1    15    1223
    1     2    1654
    1     1    1000
```

Then you can generate Version, sorted as you wish, with a query whenever you need it.

```
SELECT [major] & "." & [minor] & "." & [release] AS Version_num
FROM [SELECT DISTINCT major, minor, release
FROM tblSample]. AS s
ORDER BY s.major DESC , s.minor DESC , s.release DESC;
```

Comment: Your solution is also good, but I can't alter DB structure at this moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be: parse the strings that you get so you extract the numerical values, place leading 0s in front when required, and output a string.
E.g.
1.2.1654 becomes 0001.0002.1654 (if you're sure the numbering won't exceed 4 characters).
Code:

```
Function NormalizeVersion(Inputstring As String) As String
' Creates sortable strings out of version numbers such as 1.6.222
Dim Elements() As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim Result As String
Elements = Split(Inputstring, ".")
For Counter = 0 To UBound(Elements)
    Select Case Counter
    Case 0 'First element
        Result = Format(Elements(Counter), "00000")
    Case Else 'Followups
        Result = Result & "." & Right("0000" & Elements(Counter), 5)
    End Select
Next Counter
NormalizeVersion = Result
End Function
```

(incorporated HansUp's performance improvement)
Then you can sort on this.

Write a VBA function that does this for you, called e.g. NormalizeVersion, then call it in your query, such as (air code):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NormalizeVersion(tblSample.Version)
FROM tblSample
ORDER BY NormalizeVersion(tblSample.Version) DESC;
```

(code fixed after comment)

Comment: I got an error `ORDER BY clause (NormalizeVersion(tblSample.Version)) conflicts with DISTINCT`

Comment: That's why I said it's air code. So it probably is something like: `SELECT DISTINCT Normalizeversion(tblSample.Version)
FROM tblSample
ORDER BY NormalizeVersion(tblSample.Version) DESC;`

Comment: ? It does work here in a sample db I just ran on Access XP. See http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20995033/test.mdb (with dummy VB function though)

Comment: OK but how it solves the issue? I still need to get rid of those padding zeroes. If I give this query as a source to list box(which is one of the places I represent this data), then it will be not so easy. I would really prefer to have some kind of predicate which will compare two versions. Is there any way?

Comment: I've extended the sample with the actual function.

Comment: You can't escape the fact that you want to display one representation and sort using another. If you have a query with a column calling the NormalizeVersion, sort on that, then you could add that as a hidden column in your listobx andsort on that while showing your listbox. See sample.

Comment: @reiniero actually you can escape it. See my answer

Comment: `Format(Elements(Counter), "00000")` executes faster than `Right("0000" & Elements(Counter), 5)`

Comment: @Conrad Frix: still seems your solution & mine are very similar. You do more in SQL, I more in VBA. Fact remains that you have to process the data to get sortable output if you don't change the database... @HansUp: thanks.